# Setting layer visibility in Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Following https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/toggle-sheet-layer-visibility I tried implementing setting layer visibility but the viewer seems to act totally randomly when I call setLayerVisible. There are three possible outcomes:

1. The layer becomes invisible just fine.
2. The layer does not become invisible but the layer selector UI shows the crossed over eye.
3. The layer does not become invisible and the layer selector UI is also unchanged.

Is the viewer functionality buggy or is there something else affecting this? When actually is it safe to call setLayerVisible to get the wanted effect if I want to hide some layers immediately after the model has loaded? Is it when Autodesk.Viewing.MODEL_LAYERS_LOADED_EVENT fires?

Also, somewhat related, the layer selector UI never shows the first layer in the list as hidden even if I click on it to hide it.

Comment: Hard to see, have you tried using `GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` ? the variety in results does infact indicate that the code is not being executed at the right time. Let me now if changing the event does anything for you. cheers

Comment: Samuel might be right, it might be related to the timing when the `setLayerVisible` is executed. But the last one souds very stragne. Could you share the 2d model demonstrating this issue to forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com? This needs to debug with viewer to check what happened. **Note.** Please remove any confidential or personal data from anything you want to share withus. Thanks!